# Standard library to escape strings (without prepared statements)

Tags: java, sql, stringescapeutils

I'm searching for a Java standard library to escape strings before using them in a SQL statement. This is mainly to prevent errors and to prevent SQL injection, too.
Unfortunately, I will not be able to use prepared statements as is is suggested in a lot of other threads.

Is there any standard library I can use?
I've seen `StringEscapeUtils` at Apache Commons but I really don't know if this is state of the art.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Apache Commons is the mature library. It may have it's short-comings, but you'd have hard time looking for a better OSS Java library for your purpose.

Comment: Hi Victor,
thank you very much for your thoughts. :)
As there are no comments to the contrary, I think I'll use the Apache Commons (that was quick) ;)

Comment: Do NOT use Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql() because it does NOT correctly escape sql to prevent sql injections. It has been removed from version 3 (allegedly because they want to discourage people using that instead of PreparedStatements, which ARE safe).

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-trivial problem and a critical one because of SQL injection security issues.  I would instead consider using SQL `?` type arguments instead of escaping.  For example, to search for a particular string:

Instead of doing:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE name = 'escapedstring1' AND password = 'escapedstring2'
```

I'd use:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = ? AND password = ?
```

You will then need to pass in the injected strings (without any escaping needed) as arguments to your SQL methods.  Here's [how to do it using JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).  Not sure if that would apply to you.

Something like:

```
String statement = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = ? AND password = ?";
try {
  PreparedStatement stmt = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(updateString);
  // notice that it is 1 based, not 0 (ick)
  stmt.setString(1, name);
  stmt.setString(2, password);
  ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Here's how [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), my ORM library, does it as an example using a [select argument](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gray, thanks for your advice. This looks pretty good to me! I'll check that. I have to figure out how much effort it will be to change the data access layer...
Again, many thanks!

Comment: I wish I could rate you with a +1. But a pop-up tells me that I need at least 15 Reputation Points to rate +1. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons, it's the very mature project.